# displaying data in mat-table angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

The code works fine when I display the data in `mat-cards`, that means I'm getting the data right. But when I'm trying to display it in `mat-tables` I get index errors. I have `matTableDataSource`, `DataSource`, `CdkTableModule` and `MatTableModule` imported as well.

**Component.ts**

```
export class DriversComponent {
constructor(private webService : WebService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private auth: AuthService) {}
ngOnInit(){
    var name = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
    this.webService.getDrivers(name);
    this.webService.getUser().subscribe();
    let dataSource = this.webService.getDrivers(name);
    let displayedColumns = ['id','name','lastname'];
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let driver of webService.drivers | async">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" [@movePanel]='state'>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{driver.employeeId}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{driver.firstName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{driver.lastName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

**webservice.ts**

```
private driverStore = [];
private driverSubjet = new Subject();
drivers = this.driverSubjet.asObservable();
constructor(private http: Http, private sb: MatSnackBar, private auth: AuthService) {
    this.getDrivers('');
}
getDrivers(user) {
    user = (user) ? '/history/' + user : '';
    this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + '/employee' + user).subscribe(response => {
        this.driverStore = response.json();
        this.driverSubjet.next(this.driverStore);
    }, error => {
        this.handleError("Unable to get drivers");
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: also, it would be very useful if you can show the json data that you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `driver` variable from the `*ngFor`directive, use the `lesson` variable from your  `*matCellDef`

```
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" [@movePanel]='state'>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.employeeId}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.firstName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastname">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Last Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let lesson">{{lesson.lastName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

You may not need the `*ngFor` at all because the `mat-table` will display the data for you and you just need to provide the data source.

Note that you may need to change how you implement your `getDrivers` function because you are not returning anything!

Comment: I change the lessons to driver ..Def="let driver">{{driver.employeeId}} and got rid of the *ngfor but still same error

Comment: i know you are getting index errors, but can you show what's the exact error message?

Comment: ERROR CONTEXT 
Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 3, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }